# Stratified random assignment: Fix bug

Tags: r, random, variable-assignment

```
library(data.table)

foo = setDT(your.data.frame) # transform your df into a data.table

dat = foo[, .SD[sample(.N, round(.N * 0.5))], by = BCS] # sample 50% of rows of each BCS

foo[subject %in% dat[, .(subject), status := "treatment"][is.na(status), status:= "control"] # assign a control treatment column
```

In the R code above, Please, does any one know why the last line of code is not working? That is: `foo[subject %in% dat[, .(subject), status := "treatment"][is.na(status), status:= "control"] # assign a control treatment column`

Comment: Hi,
please share 'your.data.frame' so we can help you.
For example you can post the result of 
`dput(head(your.data.frame))`.

Comment: > subject<-1:10
>  data<-data.frame(cbind(subject,Z.sim,x))
>  foo = setDT(data)
> 
>  dat = foo[, .SD[sample(.N, round(.N * 0.5))], by = Z.sim]
>  foo[subject %in% dat[, .(subject), status:= "treatment”][is.na(status), status:= "control”]

Comment: Z.sim=rbinom(n=N,size=1,prob=0.5)
> data<-data.frame(cbind(Z.sim,x))
> data
   Z.sim           x
1      1  0.47306730
2      0  0.93899829
3      0 -0.60157871
4      1 -0.71526891
5      1 -0.41570258
6      0 -0.89176045
7      0 -0.53539250
8      0 -0.73247058
9      1 -0.04538196
10     1 -0.43329695